# Functional Testing For Java

Tags: java, servlets, integration-testing

I want to write some functional tests for a java servlet and I want to make sure it works with all the filters and other random java web stuff that might interfere with the servlet. Is there a nice way to do this in java?

I noticed the play framework has a really nice way of doing functional tests.

```
import play.test.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {

    @Test
    public void testTheHomePage() {
        Response response = GET("/");
        assertStatus(200, response);
    }
```

}

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/test

Something like that would be great but I guess I'm getting my hopes up. :)

Comment: http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html -> i think is what i was after

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/movies/intro.mov) is one option. It has the ability to export the tests to JUnit 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Cactus tool](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) extends JUnit and allows you to test server-side code.  For example, it provides a `ServletTestCase` that allows you to run code as it would in the Servlet, `FilterTestCase`, `JspTestCase`, etc. - see the [Features page](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/features.html) for more details.  They also reference the [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) project (which hasn't had much recent activity).

Comment: that's kind of what i want but i would like it be much more simpler. i don't want to deploy wars. i would just like to extend a TestClass and maybe specify a web.xml descriptor and then everything should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use Selenium +  [FluentLenium](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium).

FluentLenium is a java framework that ease the use of Selenium.

It target numerous web browsers.